# problem with url when calling wcf service by httpWebRequest

Tags: wcf, httpwebrequest

When I call manually wcf service what should I type in url place :

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)as HttpWebRequest;
```

should be there url to my svc file

```
http://localhost/service/LMTService.svc
```

or wsdl

```
http://localhost/service/LMTService.svc?wsdl
```

or url to service action ?

```
http://localhost/service/LMTService.svc/soap/GetSerializedSoapData
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the binding of the endpoint. If using a SOAP binding (i.e., `basicHttpBinding`, `wsHttpBinding`, etc), the request URI should be the **endpoint** address (not the service address). Also, in some SOAP versions (such as SOAP11, used in `basicHttpBinding`), you need to specify the *action* as a HTTP header. If you're using `webHttpBinding` (with `webHttp` behavior) the address is the address of the endpoint, plus the UriTemplate (which by default is just the method name) of the operation you want to call.

The code below shows a `HttpWebRequest`-based request being sent to two endpoints, a one using `BasicHttpBinding`, one using `WebHttpBinding`.

```
public class StackOverflow_7525850
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        int Add(int x, int y);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
    public static string SendRequest(string uri, string method, string contentType, string body, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        string responseBody = null;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Method = method;
        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (string headerName in headers.Keys)
            {
                req.Headers[headerName] = headers[headerName];
            }
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
        {
            req.ContentType = contentType;
        }

        if (body != null)
        {
            byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
            req.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
            req.GetRequestStream().Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse resp;
        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
        }

        if (resp == null)
        {
            responseBody = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Response is null");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
            foreach (string headerName in resp.Headers.AllKeys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", headerName, resp.Headers[headerName]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            if (respStream != null)
            {
                responseBody = new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream returned null");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("  *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*  ");
        Console.WriteLine();

        return responseBody;
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new BasicHttpBinding(), "basic");
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WebHttpBinding(), "web").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        string soapBody = @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
  <s:Body>
    <Add xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
      <x>44</x>
      <y>55</y>
    </Add>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>";
        SendRequest(baseAddress + "/basic", "POST", "text/xml", soapBody, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/ITest/Add" } });

        SendRequest(baseAddress + "/web/Add", "POST", "text/xml", "<Add xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><x>55</x><y>66</y></Add>", null);

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that great explanation ;) I always curious how people know that stuff ;) Books, experience etc...

Comment: The easiest way to find out what the request is supposed to be is to create a WCF client (using `ChannelFactory<T>`) using *the same binding, and the same behavior(s)* which you have on the server; then use that client to send a request, then use a tool such as Fiddler to see what the client did.